# Get specific data from an jQuery $(this) object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a node tree and want to fetch certain data attributes from these nodes when clickin on them.

I can't figure out how to get the right data from the object recived when clicking on it.

```js
var simple_chart_config = {
  chart: {
    container: "#tree"
  },
  nodeStructure: {
    text: {
      name: "King Miro",
      title: "King"
    },
    children: [{
      text: {
        name: "King Randor",
        title: "King"
      },
      children: [{
        text: {
          name: "He-Man",
          title: "Master of the Universe"
        },},{        
          text: {
            name: "She-Ra",
            title: "Princess"
          },
      }]
    }, {
      text: {
        name: "Skeletor",
        title: "Lord of Destruction"
      },
    }, ]
  }
}

var my_chart = new Treant(simple_chart_config);

$('body').on('click', '.Treant .node', function() {
    alert($(this).attr("title"));
    console.log($(this));    
});
```

```css
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { margin:0; padding:0; }
table { border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; }
fieldset,img { border:0; }
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var { font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; }
caption,th { text-align:left; }
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { font-size:100%; font-weight:normal; }
q:before,q:after { content:''; }
abbr,acronym { border:0; }

body { background: #fff; }
/* optional Container STYLES */
.chart { height: 600px; margin: 5px; width: 900px; }
.Treant > .node { padding: 3px; border: 1px solid #484848; border-radius: 3px; }
.Treant > .node img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.Treant .collapse-switch { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; }
.Treant .node.collapsed { background-color: #DEF82D; }
.Treant .node.collapsed .collapse-switch { background: none; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/treant-js/1.0/Treant.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/treant-js/1.0/Treant.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.js"></script>




<div id="tree">
</div>
```

So now I'm trying to fetch the *name:* and *title:*

I tried with many different versions of *$(this).attr("")* and *val()*. Trying to fetch via div class and similar.

I'm stuck right now.

Comment: what does $(this).data("text") returns ?

Comment: Can you post HTML of a node?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have added working snippet. No need to downvote -_-

Comment: @StéphaneAmmar It gives Undefined. I added a working snippet to play with.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I added a working snippet to play with.

Comment: Try by removing space between the two css selectors, like `$('body').on('click', '.Treant.node', function() {...});`

Comment: @Bharadwaj The on click is working. It's how to get the Name and title from the node that I can't figure out.

Comment: Do you want to access the name and title of the clicked html tag?

Comment: @sumpen for that you need to see how the html is actually constructed at the client side. Whatever `this` is referring, is that really contain attribute by name `title`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj I made a console.log with _this_. If you use your debug mode in like Chrome, you see the console log.  There you see both ***Title*** and ***Name*** under _div.node_ -> _Data:_ -> _treenode_ ->_Text:_. That is what I want to fetch.

Comment: @sumpen those are not associated with the attributes for that node. If you want to select the title and name, make use of the `p` tag which is generated as a child to that node. Get the inner text from them

Comment: @sumpen: You don't know who voted or how. You only know who commented. If you assume you know how specific people voted, you'll be wrong more often than right; and in any case, comments on votes are pointless at best and frequently counter-productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your build DOM to take the correct text that you need : `$(this).find(".node-name")` and `$(this).find(".node-title")`

```js
var simple_chart_config = {
  chart: {
    container: "#tree"
  },
  nodeStructure: {
    text: {
      name: "King Miro",
      title: "King"
    },
    children: [{
      text: {
        name: "King Randor",
        title: "King"
      },
      children: [{
        text: {
          name: "He-Man",
          title: "Master of the Universe"
        },},{        
          text: {
            name: "She-Ra",
            title: "Princess"
          },
      }]
    }, {
      text: {
        name: "Skeletor",
        title: "Lord of Destruction"
      },
    }, ]
  }
}

var my_chart = new Treant(simple_chart_config);

$('body').on('click', '.Treant .node', function() {
    alert($(this).find(".node-name").text());
    alert($(this).find(".node-title").text());
    console.log($(this));    
});
```

```css
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { margin:0; padding:0; }
table { border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; }
fieldset,img { border:0; }
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var { font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; }
caption,th { text-align:left; }
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { font-size:100%; font-weight:normal; }
q:before,q:after { content:''; }
abbr,acronym { border:0; }

body { background: #fff; }
/* optional Container STYLES */
.chart { height: 600px; margin: 5px; width: 900px; }
.Treant > .node { padding: 3px; border: 1px solid #484848; border-radius: 3px; }
.Treant > .node img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.Treant .collapse-switch { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; }
.Treant .node.collapsed { background-color: #DEF82D; }
.Treant .node.collapsed .collapse-switch { background: none; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/treant-js/1.0/Treant.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/treant-js/1.0/Treant.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.js"></script>




<div id="tree">
</div>
```